# Mediaelement not working WIndowsPhone8.1 (silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

i've used a single mediaelement in my windows phone 8.1 silverlight app and changing its source using C#, my code

private void ButtonNextPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageLeftBelow.Style = ImageLeftShown.Style;

```
    alpha += 1;
    alphaplay.Source = new Uri("///Assets/MP3/" + alpha + ".mp3");

    alphaplay.Play();
  if (alpha ==26)
  {
      next.IsEnabled = false;
  }
}
```

but my code is not working fine and not playing audio. I've also tried
`"ms-appx:///Assets/MP3/" + alpha + ".mp3"` its also not working but my code working fine on window store app and windows phone 8.1 app. pease tell me how can i play multiple audio using a single mediaelement in windows phone 8.1 (silverlight)

Comment: Are the mp3 files build action set to content?

Comment: my code is working fine, not giving me any error but my mediaelement not giving any response, i have this issue on windowphone 8.1(silverlight)app but my code works successfully on windowsphone8.1 app

Comment: I think your uri is wrong.  Try something like this new uri(Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, @"MP3/" + alpha + ".mp3")

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem caused by having 3 MediaElements in the same page, make sure you only have one.

If it still doesn't work, this is tested:

```
Sound.Source = new Uri("Assets/MP3/" + alpha + ".mp3", UriKind.Relative);
```

(without the .Play(), add a MediaOpened event instead):

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Sound" AutoPlay="False" 
                  MediaOpened="Sound_MediaOpened" 
                  MediaFailed="Sound_MediaFailed" />
```

|

```
    private void Sound_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Sound.Play();
    }

    private void Sound_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ErrorException.Message + " ERROR playing sound " + Sound.Source.ToString());

    }
```

if there is an error, you'll see its details in the output log.